# How to display only new added data in sql within last 1 minute

Tags: php

My sql `date` format is `2015-02-25 19:45:28`

So I want make my php query which display newly added post from current time to within last 1 minute.

If the post occurred time is 20:20:00 and my query's current time is 20:20:10, it will be display the post. but if my query's current time is 20:22:00 (more then 1 minute from post occurred time) , it will not display anything.

My 1st try: which display last post more then 1 hours also.

```
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 60);
// here 60 for last 60 second
$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comment WHERE qazi_id='1012' AND `date` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
```

My 2nd try: Don't display anything last added.

```
$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comment WHERE qazi_id='1012' AND date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date1minute = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 minute'));
$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comment WHERE qazi_id='1012' AND date >= '$date1minute' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
```

or:

```
$date1minute = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date("H"),date("i") - 1, date("s") , date("m") , date("d") , date("Y") ));
$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comment WHERE qazi_id='1012' AND date >= '$date1minute' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
```

Comment: Not working, Display before 2 hours data. Thank you.

Comment: have you set your default timezone before? date_default_timezone_set()

Comment: and just: $date1minute = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: Your's 1st one is working, This is my wrong, I upload my file in wrong directory of my web. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can do something like:

```
select * from table where YEAR(date) = 2015 and MONTH(date) = 1 and DAY(date) = 1 and MINUTE(date) = 1
```

So you probably have to take the current time and do a subtraction from the DB. Also I never tried to do this with `MINUTE()`.

E//
I found a better soltution:

```
select * from table where date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ;
```

Comment: Check my edit I believe thats what you are looking for.

Comment: It has to otherwise something is wrong in your DB or code.